# Can't instal laravel

Tags: php, laravel

preg_match(): Allocation of JIT memory failed, PCRE JIT will be disabled. T
  his is likely caused by security restrictions. Either grant PHP permission
  to allocate executable memory, or set pcre.jit=0

Comment: What’s steps have you taken? What’s your environment?

Comment: Hi Dicky! Welcome to SO. Could you try to reformulate your question? Solely dumping errors is not useful for providing a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a PHP 7.3 bug.

For a quick solution, edit your php.ini file and disable PHP PCRE JIT

As shown below:

```
pcre.jit=0
```